# CMS user cannot see "add child page" button

Tags: wagtail

I am trying to use Wagtail within a pre-existing Django project. I have installed the CMS, and it seems to be working well within the existing Django admin - I can authenticate using one of Django admin's users and see the CMS UI, all good.

But: No matter what I try, as an admin user, I cannot see the "Add Child Page" button at the URL of the page e.g /cms/pages/3/. The "Add Child Page" lozenge icon does not show. This is a bit of a pain, because all tutorials and examples assume that this icon is already showing!

The user I am logged-in as is set as "is_superuser" = 't' in auth_user, and one of the two groups the user is in, has been granted ALL wagtail permissions within Django admin (I was desperate!), but still no dice. I've also tried giving ALL perms to other (non-admin) users, and logging-in as them, but still cannot see the button.

I have created a basic HomePage that subclasses Page and I still see no way to create one. delving deeper, I see that one of the user's groups (auth_group.id=1) has the "add" permission in "wagtailcore_grouppagepermission" for the page I am viewing in the CMS which appears correct.

I am new to Python/Django, so I may have missed something obvious!

- Django 2.2
- Wagtail 2.8.1
- CentOS
- Python 3.6
- (Docker multi-service setup through docker-compose using CentOS)

[UPDATE]

I can see that the following line is failing the test for `specific_class` being anything other than `None`. If I hack the line to return `True`, I see the button in the CMS UI:

./core/models.py:

```
def can_add_subpage(self):
    ...
    if specific_class is None or not specific_class.creatable_subpage_models():
        print('##', specific_class) # None
        return False
    ...
```

Why would `specific_class` be `None`? What exactly *is* `specific_class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `subpage_types` declaration:  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/model_reference.html?highlight=parent_page#wagtail.core.models.Page.subpage_types

Also see `parent_page_types` below that.

Comment: Thanks. I added `subpage_types` and `parent_page_types` to my pagetypes, generated migrations and ran them. I still don't see the button after reloading the browser. I guess my point is here: This is an out of the box install, I don't understand why I need to write any logic, just to _create_ a page?

Comment: I blew the lot away, maintained the `subpage_types` and `parent_page_types` and re-built the app. The button is now showing! I will mark your answer as the working, but my comment still holds - if these attrs are required on data-models, wny do I not see it in examples? Why doesn't Wagtail come with a single "working" pagetype OOTB?

Comment: The Wagtail docs are complete (and quite good) but not great.  The Wagtail Bakery demo is the most well-known demo.  In this example models file you'll see that they've declared subpage or parent page types:  https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/blob/master/bakerydemo/breads/models.py.